# Apache 2 on Ubuntu shows 403 forbidden on certain urls

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, apache2, http-status-code-403

I have a Zend Framework application. Almost all of my urls work fine.  However, any url that starts with /resources gives me a 403 forbidden error (e.g.: /resources/add, /resources/edit). The strange thing is, when I tested it on my Windows machine via XAMP, everything worked fine. Is there something special about urls starting with /resources that makes Apache2 think it should not allow access?

Comment: Did u check the status code is coming from zend famework or not? Are you using zend framework 2?

Comment: Apache log output will be helpful to diagnose your problem. Check in ```/var/log/apache2```

Comment: I'm using ZF1. The status code was coming from Apache, not Zend. I renamed the controller and it seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems a permissions problem, nothing related to URLs. Check directories to be 755 and files 644 in the Ubuntu server where you deployed your application.

Run this in the root directory of your application and should get you going:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```